# My app closes device low memory

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-alarms, low-memory

I am developing an app for android 4.0 that uses services. The app works fine and does not crash. However, when I start a heavy app on my Galaxy s3 the app closes, for example. When I use Candy Crash my app crashes for no reason.

Is it because that device is on low memory and my app doesn't close correctly?
Or maybe it is because I use getApplicationContext() inside the service?

my service only activated on a specific time.

thanks for your help. you can see the problem yourself by downloading it 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digicode.keepintouch

this is the code of the service:
public void startRemindersService(Context context) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);

```
    myIntent.putExtra(CONSTANTS.CONTACT_ID, "-1");

    int id = 2;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, id,
            myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
```

}

Comment: Is your service a foreground service ? Cause if it is not android can kill it anytime if necessary

Comment: no it is not, how can make it foreground?

Comment: Is it actually crashing with an error message popping up, or does it silently close in the background? If it's actually crashing, you should look for a stack trace in Logcat. Maybe there is an Exception happening in one of the teardown methods.

Comment: Actually TenFour04 is right, your service could possibly be crashing, look for the stacktrace !! If there are no critical errors you should make it foreground. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Now it is working.

In the service onStart() I called for foreground and placed an empty notification. now it is working just fine. 

thanks!